# How to apply a custom namespace to an external library without changing its source?

Tags: php, namespaces

Is it possible to use an external PHP library with custom namespace, without changing its source?

I want to use all external libraries with namespace prefix "ext".

For example, I want to be able to instantiate [Predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis) 's Client class as new ext\Predis\Client() instead of new Predis\Client() (from root).

ps.: I'm autoloading all internal classes like this:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class)
{
  $path = str_replace("\\", "/", $class);

  $file = __DIR__ . "/" . $path . ".php";

  require_once $file;
});
```

Comment: Better idea.... change any namespace that you use for your Predis wrapper rather than try to change a 3rd party namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. Namespaces are resolved at compile time. It also contradicts the [PSR standards](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/#2-specification):

> The fully qualified class name MUST have a top-level namespace name,
>   also known as a “vendor namespace”.